# Creating own Report in Odoo: t-field for date, Customer ID etc.?

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

First of all I'm kinda new to Odoo and I'm trying to understand some Basic logic. I created my own Report based on the Basic Report of Odoo.

There are a lot of fields like `t-field="o.date_invoice"` or `t-field="o.partner_id` etc. which work really fine but where can I find all functions? Is there any list?

For Example I Need a Field for the order date and for the print date or for a Customer ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `t-field` attribute you can access and print fields from the actual model or from a related model, for example with the following element you can print the content of the phone column (field) of the actual record:

```xml
<span t-if="o.phone" 
      t-field="o.phone" />
```

Explanation of `t-field` in the documentation:

> The t-field directive can only be used when performing field access
>   (a.b) on a "smart" record (result of the browse method). It is able to
>   automatically format based on field type, and is integrated in the
>   website's rich text edition.

Check [this link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html) for further information if you want to build reports and [this one](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html), where you can read about some the elements that you can use in Qweb

In addition, you can check [here](https://github.com/sotogarcia/sublime-odoo-snippets/wiki/report) a list of some attributes that you can use in a Qweb template